# Visual Studio 2022 DLL Search Path

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have an executable which uses TBB. When debugging in Visual Studio 2022 the wrong TBB DLL is being loaded - the one from Visual Studio install, not the one I am using.

I've tried setting the PATH variable in launch.vs.json

```
 "PATH": "c:/mytbb"
```

but I can see inside my debug process that VS is adding its path first

```
 "PATH": "<install-dir>\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64;c:/mytbb"
```

How would I force VS to load my TBB and/or disable it from adding its own search path first (last might be ok)

Comment: That's the kind of trouble one gets when not creating a project.  Work around it by copying tbb.dll into the build directory so the PATH doesn't matter.

Comment: [Dynamic-link library search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Answer (score 0):

If you use LoadLibrary, you could use [SetDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to add directories to the search path used to find application DLLs.

I think the easiest way is the method proposed by Hans, just replace it without considering the path.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's isn't a good solution to this question, I'd call this a missing feature / issue in Visual Studio.

As suggested, you can copy the DLLs to your exe's directory but that's not a scalable solution for projects with multiple EXE's (think 200 EXEs referencing TBB - its quite a mess).

SetDLLDirectory isn't an option either as the DLL is loaded before the program executes.

Comment: In this case, you might consider using a script to copy the tbb.